# How to access array in another page after sending through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a array `student`. I need to pass this array in another php page via `POST`, not from `GET`, because it can contains thousands of characters.

I am trying to open new page `sheet.php` and echo the array `student`, I do simply checking echo `$_POST['mnu']`, but it is showing **undefined index** error.

```
var http = null;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    http = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}
http.open('POST','sheet.php',true);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(http.readyState==4 && http.status==200){
        window.open('sheet.php','_blank')
    }
}
http.send('mnu='+JSON.stringify(student));
```

Comment: surely the above will effectively make 2 requests to `sheet.php` - a POST request and then, when that succeeds, a GET request?

Comment: if you are using jquery just use this without the above code ```$.post('sheet.php',{mnu:student},function() {window.open('sheet.php','_blank')});```

Comment: @Talal, I tried using `$.post`, it redirects but same problem `undefined index $_POST['mnu']`. Is there any other way to access ?? I am doing simply `if(isset($_POST['mnu'])){echo $_POST['mnu'];}`

Comment: dude the ajax request would have data posted after the success of the request it would open ```sheet.php``` and this time there is no data posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @RamRaider commented.. you're making two requests to `sheet.php`. The first being a "silent" POST request and the second being a GET request after the first POST request has successfully completed.

[image: Request count]

The second request won't share the payload of the first.

If I under stand correctly the below code should do what you are wanting...

```
// Create a form element
// <form action="sheet.php" method="post"></form>
var tempForm = document.createElement('form');
tempForm.setAttribute('action', 'sheet.php');
tempForm.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
tempForm.setAttribute('target', '_blank'); // Open in new tab

// Create an input field
// <input name="mnu" value="...">
var tempInput = document.createElement('input');
tempInput.setAttribute('name', 'mnu');
tempInput.setAttribute('value', JSON.stringify(student)); // Set field value

// Add the input to the form
tempForm.appendChild(tempInput);


// Add the form to the body in order to post
document.body.appendChild(tempForm);

// Submit the form
tempForm.submit();

// Remove the form
document.body.removeChild(tempForm);
```

And if you're using jQuery you can simplify the above code..

```
$('<form>', {
    action: 'sheet.php',
    method: 'POST',
    target: '_blank',
    html: $('<input>', {
        name: 'mnu',
        value: JSON.stringify(student)
    }).prop('outerHTML')
}).appendTo($('body')).submit().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `http.send('mnu='+JSON.stringify(student));` to `http.send(JSON.stringify(student));`

And then in your `sheet.php` use `json_decode($_POST)` to fetch your **POST** data

Comment: what to `decode` in php file ??, `json_decode()` expects 1 parameter, and it doesn't `student` array

Comment: ``http.send(JSON.stringify(student));`` means you turn your JSON object into a string. Once posted to the page ``sheet.php`` you need to turn it back to an object, so you can use something like ``$student = json_decode($_POST)``. Then you should be able to access your ``student`` directly as an object (e.g ``$student->name``)